# Need advice on multitab form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i need an advice on how to implement my form. 
I have a requirement: i need a form that spans through 5 tabs. Each tab has around 10 fields, some of them empty, some of them must contain data from db and be non editable.
Each of these tabs must be a part of one form that is submitted to my controller.

The question is: what is the best way to implement this? 
I was thinking about having partial views on each tab, each view would have its own model class. After form gets filled all data from all partials would go to action that will take care of all of it.
Any advices? 
I am using ASP.NET MVC 1, Entity Framework 1, mvc extensions from  Telerik and jQuery

Comment: Just one advice. Don't use multitab forms. It's usability hell.

Comment: I know exactly what you are talking about, but they WANT me to do it this way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the easy way to do this is to have one single form split up into tabs via `<div>`'s.  Then use one of the bazillion jquery/javascript tabbing libraries to switch between them.

Validation and UI flow control will be so much simpler.  A single form, single POST action method,single place for validation errors.  Splitting up this problem with partials and multiple views just makes things harder.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Which jQuery Tab library would you reccomend that is lightweight and easy to learn?

Comment: Probably the one built into JQuery UI.  That way you can theme all the UI widgets and share that across your site.

Comment: There is indeed one in jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
But like you say, if that's no good, there are tons more out there. I would also follow this approach - 1 form, several `divs` for tabs.

Comment: @Rob yes it's simpler, but the UX of a multi-tab editor is tough to get right.  I like to force the user to finish whatever they're doing on the current tab (e.g., save changes) before switching to another tab.  Otherwise you have to switch users back to other tabs when validation fails or do some sort of tab markup to indicate which tabs have validation failures.

Comment: @manu08 I don't understand, there is nothing to stop you from validating the users input on one tab before allowing them to move to the next? The question was more around the architecture (usage of partials etc.) which should have little relevant on the resulting UX.